# How to Process Large JSON Files with Python

Tags: python, data, json

I've been using Python for quite some time now, scripting command line tools, etc.  I'm just now moving to Data Analysis with the language; are there any tips for handling larger json files.  Particularly, determining appropriate specs for a system, threading/multiprocessing, etc.

I'm finding that it's taking an excessive amount of time to handle basic tasks; I've worked with python reading and processing large files (i.e. Log files), and it seems to run a lot faster.

Example, I'm downloaded a json file from catalog.data.gov for traffic violations.  The file is 758Mb in size and it takes a long time to do something very simple.

```
>>> import ijson
>>> 
>>> filename = 'rows.json'
>>> with open(filename, 'r') as f:
...     objects = ijson.items(f, 'meta.view.columns.item')
...     columns = list(objects)
...     print columns[0]
...     f.close()
... 


{u'name': u'sid', u'format': {}, u'dataTypeName': u'meta_data', u'fieldName': u':sid', u'renderTypeName': u'meta_data', u'position': 0, u'id': -1, u'flags': [u'hidden']}
```

I've worked with json before, but this seems to be taking a long time for something so simple.  I'm did this on a laptop with 4GB of RAM (~2G free).

Comment: First try [pandas.read_json](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html). The real solution is to upgrade your computer because the file's size and your laptop's memory are considered small today. Also consider using command line tools like `jq` instead. Welcome to the site!

Comment: I think StackOverflow is a better place for this question.

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407430/how-to-speed-up-process-of-loading-and-reading-json-files-in-python